# AWS - Activating conda environment with cloud-init (User Data Field)

Tags: amazon-web-services, anaconda, conda

We are trying to run batch scripts on load on a AWS EC2 instance using userdata (which I understand is based off of cloud-init). Since the code runs in a conda environment, we are trying to activate it prior to running the Python/Pandas code. We noticed that the PATH variable isn't getting set correctly. (even though it was set correctly prior to making the image, and is set correctly for all users after SSH'ing into instance)

We've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

source activate path/to/conda_env

bash path/to/script.sh
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash

conda run -n path/to/conda_env bash path/to/script.sh
```

Nothing appears to work. This code runs the script while sshing into an EC2 instance but not while using EC2 cloud-init userdata (launching a script at launch). I've verified the script is indeed working at launch by creating a simple text file with user data, so it is working when starting an instance...

Comment: "Nothing appears to work." - this is not specific. Why exactly it does not work? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, nothing. Just doesn't execute the code. You can see my script ramping up in top in a regular ssh session, but it doesn't show up when running from cloud-init.

Comment: Did you check any log files, specifically `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`?

Comment: Yes, and it appears to be running to completion -- just not activating conda and executing the script needing the conda env. I also verified cloud-init was executing my script by making a simple text file.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what do you mean by "not activating conda and executing the script needing the conda env". If there are no errors, then your code is executed correctly and could-init finishes. You conda was activited for the moment could-init run. What do you expect this code to do exactly?

Comment: Is there any development on this question? I have a similar issue. I tried 
bash ./conda_installer.sh -b && /miniconda3/bin/conda init && source ~/.bashrc && conda create -n "my_env" python=3.8 gdal -y && conda activate my_env && source ~/.bashrc &&  conda env export > env.yml. 

But env has name=Base, not my_env. It would be great to be able to activate an env and work with the env in the AWS User Data field.